# User entered javascript less safer than the browser web developer tool?

Tags: javascript, user-input

I'd like to add a small feature to my webpage where a user can write javascript to do some data manipulation (e.g., create a new object from data table - ideally, I'd like to disable non-necessary features in JS such as accessing the server through ajax, etc.).  Is this a really bad idea in terms of security? It seems the sites that allow such a feature (e.g., w3school try-it feature) uses server side validation.  Someone on Stackoverflow suggested running the user code in a web worker thread is safer, which I can do.

But my question is, in general, most browsers these days come with developer tools and console where you can write and execute javascript code. So adding user JS editor feature won't make the application any more vulnerable than it is.  Am I thinking it right?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that an app is not immune to a user writing extra code to execute in their own browser.

However, a user can not normally write code to execute in *other people's browsers* and enabling that behavior in your app could enable an attack or other unauthorized behavior of the app.  By enabling one user to add javascript to pages viewed and executed by others, this attack vector is enabled.

The two main approaches are trust and sandboxing.  Trust may be ok within a small community where identities are known and consequences for misuse can ensue.... but is still problematic. Sandboxing JS in the browser is non trivial as well. There isn't really a way to block access to `window` because `this` can become `window`, there are tricks with `eval`, etc... so most sandboxes fail.

Answer (score 1):

In theory this is "safe". Safe in the sense that the user can do it anyway with things like the debugging console or even using the `"javascript:"` protocol in the address bar.

What's unsafe is saving these scripts in the database. Or rather, allowing one users's scripts to run in another users's session.

What the user executes himself is his own risk. If he deletes all his data then that's his fault. Just like allowing user access to the `rm` command on Linux.

What you want to protect is other users data from the user's script.

This is one reason people keep trying to inject javascript in forum comments - so that when other people view the hacked comment the script can steal information that would otherwise be inaccessible to the hacker.